# Allow Read access to one specific collection in Firebase Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

On my android app, I am using Firebase Firestore to store a collection of "usernames" to be queried BEFORE the user signs in to check whether the chosen username is available or not.

Currently my project has 2 main collections: "users" and "usernames". I am trying to allow Read access only in the "usernames" collection. My program fails because when I try to query the "usernames" collection before the user is authenticated it says I don't have the right permissions.

My rules are very basic, but I was wondering if it is possible to modify them in some way for my project to work. Rules are as follows:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

A visual idea what the firestore database looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you want to treat the "usernames" collection differently than everything else, call it out by name, and assign full read access to everyone:

```
    match /usernames/{id} {
      allow read: if true;
    }
```

I suggest taking some time to study the [documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to better understand how they work, an learn how to make rules on your own.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's customary to click to checkbox to mark the answer as correct.